# Can an Assassin rogue's Infiltration Expertise feature be used to create a false identity for another character?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, rogue

[Assassin rogues](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/rogue#Assassin) (PHB p. 97) get the Infiltration Expertise feature at level 9, which can be used to

> spend seven days and 25 gp to establish the history, profession, and affiliations for an identity.

Could the information the Rogue creates be given to another person to allow them to assume the false identity?

Answer (score 16):

The skill description is quite clear:

> Infiltration Expertise: Starting at 9th level, you can unfailingly
>   create false identities **for yourself**. You must spend seven days and 25
>   gp to establish the history, profession, and affiliations for an
>   identity. You can't establish an identity that belongs to someone
>   else. For example, you might acquire appropriate clothing, letters of
>   introduction , and official-looking certification to establish
>   **yourself** as a member of a trading house from a remote city so you can
>   insinuate **yourself** into the company of other wealthy merchants.
>   Thereafter, if you adopt the new identity as a disguise, other
>   creature believe you to be that person until given an obvious reason
>   not to.

The skill doesn't only create a false identity, it makes you fit into that identity, making you do things that you normaly wouldn't, like changing your manner of speaking, your walk and how you act to fit that role.

So by RAW I would say that's a no, but it never hurts to ask your DM. As a DM, I would constantly ask for performance checks to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

Your assassin ability lets you create a false persona.  You get certain special advantages, such as "if you adopt the new identity as a disguise, other creature believe you to be that person until given an obvious reason not to.", and these advantages do not carry over to others, but other characters can certainly disguise themselves as the fictitious person you have created!

Consider, for example, the [doppelganger](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Doppelganger#content).  If your assassin PC established himself a ship's captain false identity and a doppelganger decided to impersonate him to steal his boat, such a transformation should not be automatically impossible just because the 'ship's captain' is secretly an assassin.  Rather, it should be run just like any other disguise attempt which seeks to imitate a specific person.

In the case of you assisting allied party members with their establishing identities, it seems difficult to argue your efforts, particularly your ability to produce supporting documentation, histories, etc, would not be enough to grant advantage on the Charisma(Deception) checks your allies would be making to convince people of their legitimacy. Other than your being able to do this beforehand, though, this isn't really any different than your just taking the 'Help' action to assist with said checks when they are made.

Answer (score 0):

The rules as written only say "unfailingly create false identities for yourself." As the rules are written, the "unfailingly" qualifier interferes with the automatic disqualification for using it on another person, in the strictest legalize.

Meaning the DM can rule that you can create false identities for other people, but the "unfailingly" modifier only applies to you, i.e., the identities you make for other people have no such promise.

You could still spend the seven days and 25 gold, but the DM would have to determine if you succeeded.

Put another way, the power grants automatic success at making disguises for yourself. It doesn't grant automatic success for disguises made for other people, but the DM may allow you a skill role, or even grant advantage, based on your experience. Likewise, a DM may simply rule it like a video game and assume no such interpretation is necessary.

But as written, the power is automatic success (unfailing) disguises for yourself only.